# How to tackle prime models and saturated models

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

> We define $T$ as the theory of equivalence relations
>   $\{R_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $R_{n+1}$ refines $R_n$. Prove that $T$
>   1) has a countable prime model; but 2) no countable $\aleph_0$-saturated
>   model.

I think I understand the definitions of prime models and $\kappa$-saturated models, but I have no intuition about them. Can you explain how one should approach this exercise?

Comment: This question is a bit funny, because we usually talk about prime and saturated models of complete theories, and your $T$ is not complete. If the definition of "prime model" is a model $M\models T$ such that $M$ embeds elementarily in every other model of $T$, then (1) is false, simply because no incomplete theory can have a prime model. Now $T$ has a completion with a prime model, so it's reasonable to interpret the question that way. But this interpretation is a problem for (2), because $T$ also has a completion with a countable $\aleph_0$-saturated model. So something is wrong.

Comment: @Ibrahim Yes, that's the argument I had in mind. "The completion" of a theory $T$ doesn't make sense in general. "A completion" of a theory $T$ is a complete theory $T'$ such that $T\subseteq T'$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman What if we assume that the refinements are such that $R_{n+1}$ splits every $R_n$ equivalence set into infinity many pieces? Is that theory complete? Does it have a prime model?

Comment: Yes, that theory is complete. And it has both a prime model and a countable saturated model.

Comment: @AlexKruckman OK. I think it is best to remove this question then? But I am still very shaky about how to do stuff with prime/saturated models. Can you indicate how to show $T$ has a prime model?

Comment: @AlexKruckman It also seems $\omega$-categorical. Is that correct?

Comment: No need to remove the question! I'll post an answer later when I have time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the discussion in the comments, I'll assume we're working with the complete theory $T$ which says that $R_0$ has infinitely many classes, and for each $n$, $R_{n+1}$ refines each class of $R_n$ into infinitely many classes. I'll give a sketch of how to analyize the countable models of $T$.

$T$ is certainly not $\omega$-categorical, simply because the formulas $R_n(x,y)$ are pairwise non-equivalent for $n\in\omega$. An $\omega$-categorical theory only has finitely many formulas up to equivalence in each tuple of variables.

The key thing to note about a model $M\models T$ is that for any finitely many elements $a_1,\dots,a_n$, if I specify for each $a_i$ some $k_i$, then there is some $b\in M$ such that for all $1\leq i\leq n$, we have $\lnot R_{k_i}(a_i,b)$, but $R_{j}(a_i,b)$ for all $j<k_i$, unless these specifications would violate transitivity. Let's call this the *extension property*. This is an important step toward proving quantifier-elimination and completeness of $T$, which you would need to do in order to make my arguments below precise.

Any theory which is not $\omega$-categorical should have a non-isolated type. In this case, there's a non-isolated $2$-type, given by by $p(x,y) = \{x\neq y\} \cup \{R_n(x,y)\mid n\in \omega\}$, asserting that $x$ and $y$ are distinct but live in the same class for all the equivalence relations. Let's denote by $R_\infty$ the equivalence relation defined by $R_\infty(x,y) \iff \bigwedge_{n\in \omega} R_n(x,y)$.

A prime model of a theory omits all of the non-isolated types, so we see that in a prime model of $T$, the $R_\infty$-classes should all have size $1$. And in fact, given a countable model $M\models T$ such that all $R_\infty$-classes have size $1$, you can show that $M$ is prime, by embedding $M$ in any other model $N\models T$ by a "forth" argument: enumerate $M$ and embed it in $N$ one point at a time using the extension property above. It's important here that all of the $R_\infty$-classes have the minimum size ($1$), so you never have to put a new element in an $R_\infty$ class in $N$ that's already full.

On the other hand, a countable saturated model $M$ should realize as many types as possible. In particular, for any finitely many elements $a_1,\dots,a_n$ in the same $R_\infty$ class, $M$ will realize the type saying that $x$ is distinct from all the $a_i$ but goes in the same $R_\infty$ class. This shows that all $R_\infty$ classes should be countably infinite. And indeed, given a countable model $M\models T$ in which all of the $R_\infty$ classes are countably infinite, you can argue that $M$ is $\aleph_0$-saturated, again using the extension property and quantifier elimination.

Ok, so we know what the prime model and countable saturated model should look like, just in terms of the sizes of the $R_\infty$-classes. How do we make sure they exist? Well, you can build them by hand: Think about a complete countably branching tree, where the branching at level $n$ is the $R_n$-classes. A path through the tree denotes an $R_\infty$ class. We want to pick countably many $R_\infty$ classes to put elements in. First, for each branch at level $0$, pick a path through the tree that starts down that branch, and color it blue. Then, for each branch at level $1$, pick a path through the tree that starts down that branch, and color it blue. Repeat. After handling each level, we'll have only colored countably many branches blue. To build the prime model, put one element in each $R_\infty$-class colored blue. To build the countable saturated model, put countably many elements in each of these classes.

Finally, note that we didn't have to pick $1$ or $\aleph_0$: we could have put any number of elements in each of the blue classes. The freedom to do this shows that $T$ has continuum-many countable models (since there are continuum-many subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, and for each subset $S\subseteq \mathbb{N}$, we can make sure that there is an $R_\infty$ class of size $n$ if and only if $n\in S$).

Comment: I don't think I completely understand your "extension property", which seems vital. In particular, what do you mean with "unless these specifications would violate transitivity"?

Comment: Also, your partial 2-type $p$ is non-isolated because $T$ is complete and there are models of $T$ that do not realize $p$, right? Is it hard to show completeness of $T$ given quantifier elimination?

Comment: Also, as I see it $p$ is in fact the only non-isolated 2-type. By quantifier elimination, the atomic formulas of the type determine the type. Since $x=y$ is already isolating, we can restrict to $x\neq y$. But $T \models \neg R_n(x, y) \to \neg R_m(x, y)$ for all $n \geq m$.

Comment: (And again THANK-YOU for all the help; you make model theory a lot more fun; my notes are very terse and provide no motivation. Any book recommendation that respects the beginner's need for motivating definitions/proofs?)

Comment: (1) Example: suppose $a_1$ and $a_2$ are equivalent up to $R_5$, but inequivalent after that. Then I can find a $b$ which is equivalent to $a_1$ up to $R_7$ and equivalent to $a_2$ up to $R_5$. But I can't ask that $b$ is also equivalent to $a_2$ in $R_6$, since that would violate transitivity. As another example, I can find $b$ which is equivalent to $a_1$ and $a_2$ up to $R_3$. But I can't ask for $b$ to be equivalent to $a_1$ up to $R_4$ and only equivalent to $a_2$ up to $R_3$, since that would violate transitivity.

Comment: (2) That's one way to see it. You can also observe that any formula mentions only finitely many of the equivalence relations. So if $(a,b)$ satisfies the $2$-type, and the two-type is isolated by $\varphi(x,y)$, then we have $\varphi(a,b)$. But then we could pick a new $b'$ which agrees with $b$ on the relations mentioned by $\varphi$, so $\varphi(a,b')$ is true, but such that $(a,b')$ doesn't satisfy the $2$-type.

Comment: (2') If a theory $T$ has quantifier elimination in a language with no constant symbols ($0$-ary function symbols) or propositional symbols ($0$-ary relation symbols), then it's complete, simply because there are no quantifier-free sentences except for $\top$ and $\bot$ (true and false). (3) That's correct, it's the only non-isolated $2$-type. (4) You're welcome. The textbook by Marker has lots of examples, and the textbook by Hodges has lots of motivation.

Comment: Which one of the two Hodges books do you recommend?

Comment: *A shorter model theory* is easier to read as a textbook. It's just an edited down version of *Model theory*, which is more of a comprehensive reference work. I assume those were the two books you had in mind? (Hodges has written more than two books)

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion. Okay. How does the Marker book complement Hodges's? More examples?

Comment: Well, different kinds of examples. And a slightly different focus. I would say Marker's book is more interested in covering connections with other areas of mathematics (that's not to say that Hodges doesn't do this too).

Comment: I have bought the Hodges's book, and it looks really good! However, I need to revamp my algebra a bit for the examples. But I don't know of any "intermediate" algebra books that are fun to read (e.g. Stillwell's elements of algebra is nice but too simple; Lang's algebra is too comprehensive). Also, I have posted a new question: if you have the time I would appreciate it if you could take a look!